# How to setup GUI for private docker registry?

Tags: user-interface, docker, docker-registry

I have setup my own private docker registry. I can able to upload images on the registry server but at the time of pulling, I need to remember the image names since there is no way to get these. Currently, I am manually checking the names by visiting the docker registry machine or I need to remember the uploaded image names. That is not feasible solution. Is there any other way to do like one GUI provided by docker hub ?

Comment: What `docker images` show?

Comment: docker images gives list of images that are locally present on my machine. But, I need to get the list of images that I already uploaded on my private docker registry server.

Comment: Not a full solution, but I put together a very basic Registry UI that shows you repos and tags: https://github.com/kevana/docker-registry-2.0-ui

Comment: If a commercial solution is no objection, there's Docker Trusted Registry; https://www.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry

Comment: @ Kevan, Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: @thaJeztah. docker trusted registry is an trail version and not a permanent one. Anyway, will go through it.

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar, what solution did you end up using? I have a similar question. I want to see the different tags, time of upload, other details about the various pushes to my private docker registry. Thanks.